# Is there any basic gc generation size and ratios for application in production

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory, jhat

How much should be the initial size of the young generation?
How much should be -XX:+NewRatio?
-XX:+SurvivourRatio?
What should be the ratio between perm and old generation.?

Answer (score 0):

Every application is different. Your best bet is to measure it yourself!

Create an automated test case which runs through a typical use case for your application. Call this from a shell script which creates random permutations of generation sizes, making sure to keep track of how long it runs for with `time`. Hold on to the fastest 10 and output them when ctrl+c is pressed.

Leave the script running overnight.

You'll have your answer in the morning =)